# Apache SetEnvIf trouble

Tags: apache, environment-variables, setenv

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIf Host "^example\.com$" myvar=1
<IfDefine myvar>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfDefine>
```

As far as I can tell, this should be working properly.  However, "myvar" does not appear to get defined when I visit from `example.com`.  I know that I have the `mod_setenvif.c` enabled (I've verified with an <IfModule> block).

Any ideas why "myvar" isn't getting defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really a ServerFault question, but anyway: `IfDefine` doesn't test environment variables, it tests the configuration options that were passed to Apache at startup. So for example, if you ran

```
apache2 -D MYVAR
```

then a section

```
<IfDefine MYVAR>
    ...
</IfDefine>
```

would get executed.

I'm not sure if there's any Apache configuration directive that acts as a conditional for environment variables, like you're looking for.

Comment: So is there a way to test for a variable set with `SetEnvIf`?

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond` to create a rewrite condition that depends on the value of an environment variable... other than that, I'm not sure if there are other directives that use environment variables. They're mostly for CGI scripts etc.