# apache setenvif doesn't set env variable if checked against HTTP Header

Tags: apache2, environment-variables

from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html

"Conditionally send MyHeader on the response if and only if header MyRequestHeader is present on the request. This is useful for constructing headers in response to some client stimulus. Note that this example requires the services of the mod_setenvif module."

```
 SetEnvIf MyRequestHeader myvalue ENV_SET
 Header set MyHeader "%D %t mytext" env=ENV_SET
```

but then from [Apache SetEnvIf trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369023/apache-setenvif-trouble) and from my testing trying to set an environment var by checking the **Authorization** header, the ENV_SET won't be set at all

SetEnvIf only sets the env variable ENV_SET for the following
    * Remote_Host
    * Remote_Addr 
    * Server_Addr 
    * Request_Method 
    * Request_Protocol
    * Request_URI

Is the documentation wrong or am I misunderstanding something ?

Using:  Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_jk/1.2.30

Answer (score 4):

Format is:

```
SetEnvIf <headername> <regex> <environment variable name and optionally a value>
```

This worked for me:

```
SetEnvIf ACTUAL_CLIENT_IP "^172\.111\.0\.27" dontlog
```

where `ACTUAL_CLIENT_IP` is the name of the HTTP header which stores the actual client IP (as opposed to the Remote_Addr field which gets overwritten with our proxy server's IP).