# Apache config for all Location except specific URI

Tags: regex, location, apache2, config, directive

I need to apply some configuration for a Location Directive.

These configurations must be applied for all location, except some `URIs` (e.g. I don't wanna change configs for `/products`, so bellow configuration must be applied for all locations, except **/products** )

```
<Location />
 # desired configurations
</Location>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done in several ways:

### 1. Using **regex**

Use regex in *Location Directive* to match all URIs, except your pattern

e.g.:

```
<Location ~ "^((?!/product).)*$">
# desired configurations
</Location>
```

---

### 2. Using < If> directive

e.g.: use `If` inside your directory:

```
<If "%{Request_URI} != '.*/product.*'">
```

or

```
<If "%{Request_URI} != '^((?!/product).)*$'">
```

---

### 3. By setting variables and using If and IfDefine

Set a variable at start of configurations, and then use directive

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*/product.*" isProd=1
...
<IfDefine isProd>
...
```

or you can use expr in If directive for comparing strings and variables.

### 4. By using another `<Location>`

It's possible to change an earlier `<Location>` section by overriding it after. For example, this will enforce authentication on everything but `/.well-known/`, a common pattern to get TLS certificates from Let's Encrypt:

```
        <Location />
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Restricted Content"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
        <Location /.well-known/>
                Require all granted
        </Location>
```

This will ask users for passwords in all of `/*` *except* for `/.well-known/*`  which will not require a password.

See the [upstream documentation on configuration sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html) for more information on this.

---

[Useful link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html)

Comment: Probably the third solution will not work. Remember that IfDefine directive doesn't test environment variables but startup options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369094/2186777

Comment: Also in the second solution replace `=!` with `!=`

Comment: The second solution results in a syntax error. In order to use a regex in an <If> clause in Apache 2.4, you must use a regex `!~` comparator as well as alternative regex syntax using `m#`. Example: `<If "%{Request_URI} !~ m#.*/product.*#">`